# Run loop after page load VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, gridview

I would like the page to load, then I will display a GIF that's LOADING DATA and then I want this loop (see below) to run until the row count is not 0.

(An SQL job has been triggered in the previous page which takes about 1 - 2 minutes to run and so I want to display the new data automatically when it appears in the database.)

I can't figure out how to programmatically get this to work, I understand that because I have this in the page_load it will run before the page loads but I'm not sure how to run it after the page has loaded

Any help, advice or tips are very welcome
Thank you

```
Sub Page_Load(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal E As EventArgs)
    Do While GridView1.Rows.Count = 0 And GridView2.Rows.Count = 0
        GridView1.DataBind()
        GridView2.DataBind()
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you need to learn about the page life-cycle in ASP.NET, and in particular the fact that the browser will NOT finish "loading" until all the page has been processed.  As Chris hints at in his "answer", you should look at AJAX... either manually through jquery/javascript, or via the `<asp:UpdatePanel>` in ASP.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using Ajax/JQuery, can you not use a timer control that posts back every  seconds and as soon as there is data in both tables then disable the timer.

Comment: `Sub Page_Load(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal E As EventArgs)  `
`Timer1.enabled = (GridView1.Rows == 0) || (GridView2.Rows == 0)  `
`End Sub  `

Comment: thanks a lot, I will consider implementing something like this